# Backbone.js View events disable enable

Tags: backbone.js

If I have a View in backbone.js and it has an event in the events list:

```
events: {
    'click #somebutton': 'clicked'         
},
clicked: function () {
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

How can I then disable/enable that event? So for instance if its clicked then 
the event is removed (the button remains on screen but is greyed out etc). When some other part of the view is updated or whatever the event 
enabled. Sure I can use jquery but I want to know if this functionality is available in backbone.

Thanks for any answers

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `delegateEvents()` and `undelegateEvents()` to redo your event binding between the DOM and your Backbone View. That said, I usually just keep the event handler and add a conditional in the handler.

```
// .disabled class (CSS) grays out the button

clicked: function(event) {
    var buttonEl = $(event.currentTarget);

    if (buttonEl.hasClass('disabled')) {
        // Do nothing
    } else {
        // Do something AND...
        buttonEl.addClass('disabled');
    }
}
```

Then you can have your other view or code simply `removeClass('disabled')` when you want to restore functionality.

**UPDATE - disabled property**

See comments, but a simpler, much better solution is to use the disabled property `disabled="disabled"` of buttons.

Comment: Thanks that's what I would do as well just wanted to make sure there wasn't a 'Correct' way of doing it.

Comment: @PaulThompson: If it really is a `<button>` then you can `$(button).prop('disabled', true)` and it won't respond to clicks anymore. This is one of the advantages to using `<button>` for, um, buttons.

Comment: Heh heh. Why is it the simplest stuff that one misses sometimes? :-) I had no idea about the disabled property but that certainly makes stuff a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Use `delegateEvents` and `undelegateEvents` for binding and unbinding events. Check for reference: [delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)