# Trouble removing one of several event listeners in a Backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to remove an event listener from a particular DOM item and having trouble. The following shows the parts of the code I'm playing with:

```
Search.Views.MainSearch = Backbone.View.extend({
    // initialization function
    events: {
        'click #search-submit' : 'searchSubmit',
        'click #some-button': 'disableSearch',
        'click #some-other-button': 'someFunction'
    }|,
    disableSearch: function(){
        // this statement works, but it removes all listeners
        $(this.el).off('click');
        // this statement doesn't work
        // $('#search-submit').off('click', this.searchSubmit);
        // This also doesn't work
        // $(this.el).off('click', this.searchSubmit);
    }
```

Clicking the #search-submit button works as expected. Clicking the #some-button item works insofar as it calls the disableSearch method. However, I can't remove just the click event from the #search-submit button. I can remove all listeners, but this doesn't suit my purpose because it removes the listener from #some-other-button as well.

Is there some way to remove just the event listeners I care about and leave the rest intact? Is there a better way to attach the event listeners in the first place? Thanks...

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542325/backbone-js-view-events-disable-enable

Answer (score 1):

You can remove an event listener on a specific element by undelegating it:

```
this.$el.off('click', '#search-submit');
```

and a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/fS278/

You cannot remove a specific function when wired by the hash of events (Backbone transforms the functions by forcing the `this` context). However, handling the `search-submit` events attachments yourself would let you unbind a function :

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #some-button': 'disableSearch',
        'click #some-other-button': 'someFunction'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        // let's make sure searchSubmit has the view as context
        _.bindAll(this, 'searchSubmit');
        // and then direct the event to the bound function
        this.$el.on('click', '#search-submit', this.searchSubmit);
    },

    disableSearch: function(){
        // this.searchSubmit is the same function as in initialize
        // it can be detached
        this.$el.off('click', this.searchSubmit);
        return false;
    },

    searchSubmit: function() {
        console.log('searchSubmit');
        return false;
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/fS278/1/